# Java Swing Making On/Off Button

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

I am trying to make an on/off button for my GUI project. I made a button, when I click on it, a message appears. I used `ActionListener` for that. When I click it again, I want that message to dissappear. I tried to use `jToggleButton` but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a matter well described in [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of using a `JToggleButton`:

```
JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton("Click Me");
ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
        int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
        if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            System.out.println("Selected"); // show your message here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Deselected"); // remove your message
        }
    }
};
toggleButton.addItemListener(itemListener);
```

You can use `JButton` and `ActionListener` as you've already started, but keep track of the current state yourself.